# How to add to an associative array in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to change an element of a zsh associative array, but I can't find any clues on the correct syntax.

The PHP equivalent would be

`$assoc['key'] = 'newvalue';`

but how can I do this in zsh?

The documentation seems to be very confusing on this, as it assumes that once you've set up an associative array, you never want to change it.

**EDIT: this is what I'm trying to do**

`% noglob ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[globbing]='fg=yellow' 
zsh: command not found: ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[globbing]=fg=yellow`

`$ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES` is defined by the zsh-syntax-highlighting plugin.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `noglob` (a precommand modifier) with an assignment statement?

Comment: Brain fade, I think — trying to avoid having to escape the square brackets. Turns out you don't need to, and the example I'd looked at had needless backslashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple, assuming you *have* an associative array.

```
typeset -A assoc
assoc[key]=newvalue
```

Comment: Could this be done in a oneliner? I'm thinking
`typeset -A assoc=[key1]=newvalue1 [key2]=newvalue2`

Comment: Yes; you can write `typeset -A assoc=(key1 newvalue1 key2 newvalue2)`.

Comment: @chepner I prefer writing it like `typeset -A assoc=([key1]=new_value1 [key2]=new_value2)`.

Comment: Funny enough, it looks like the the most compatible syntax is what @chepner has written : `typeset -A assoc=(key1 newvalue1 key2 newvalue2)`. The version @Franklin has provided seems not to work properly on Ubuntu (zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)).

Comment: The ksh/bash-compatible `([key]=value)` syntax was added in 5.5.