# In standard shell syntax, dictionary elements can be added in batch es, what to do in the z shell?

Tags: shell, zsh

In the standard shell, a dictionary can be assigned a value using the following syntax:

```sh
$ declare -A dict
$ dic=([key1]="value1" [key2]="value2" [key3]="value3")
```

However, this doesn't work in z shell, how can I accomplish the same in z shell?

Comment: Make `dic=(...` `dict=(...` See also [How to add to an associative array in zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37387781/3422102) and the Zsh manual [5.4.2: Using associative arrays](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html)

Comment: "standard shell" doesn't have arrays.

Comment: Newer versions of zsh understand that style of associative array syntax, older ones only understand alternating keys and values. `declare -A dict=(key1 val1 key2 val2)`

Comment: Define what you mean by the term _the standard shell_. What standard are you talking about?

Comment: `declare -A` is `bash`, not "standard". The POSIX shell standard doesn't include arrays of any kind.